# How do equations of motion in BF theory imply triviality of powers of observables?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, topological-field-theory, chern-simons-theory

Following the lectures of Nathan Seiberg at PiTP in 2015 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pqgNrVTQ4yM&t=666s, consider $U(1)$ BF theory in 2D
$$S(B,A)=\frac{n}{2\pi}\int_\Sigma B\text{d}A,$$
and the operator
$$V(x_0)=e^{iB(x_0)}.$$
I want to understand why $V(x_0)^n=1$. In particular, I see how inserting such an operator in the path integral is equivalent to modifying the action by
$$S\mapsto S+nB(x_0)=\frac{n}{2\pi}\int_{\Sigma}B\text{d}(A+\text{d}\theta),$$
where $\theta$ is an angle function around $x_0$ so that
$$\text{d}(\text{d}\theta)=2\pi\delta(x,x_0)\text{d}^2x.$$
This is equivalent to doing a large gauge transformation of $A$, and thus such an operator insertion is trivial. However, I am worried this argument is wrong, for both in the lectures and in the papers D-Brane Charges in Five-brane Backgrounds of Juan Maldacena, Greg Moore and Nathan Seiberg https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0108152 and Coupling a QFT to a TFT and Duality of Anton Kapustin and Nathan Seiberg https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.0740, it is claimed that the equations of motion are necessary in the argument.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v3): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.